# How do i count unique (distinct) values in my MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

I am trying to count the unique filenames linked per barcode.

Im running the following query

```
select filename,barcode,item_code from images
join imports on import_id = imports.id
order by item_code desc, barcode;
```

and i get the following results:

```
filename                        barcode         item_code
5021523203124_1401260.jpg       5021523203124   9974
5021526203121_1390655.jpg       5021523203124   9974
5021526203121_1390655.jpg       5021523203124   9974
5021526203121_1390655.jpg       5021523203124   9974
```

I would like to have the following as results

```
filename                    img_count   barcode         item_code
5021523203124_1401260.jpg   1           5021523203124   9974
5021526203121_1390655.jpg   3           5021523203124   9974
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aggregate with `GROUP BY`:

```
select
    filename,
    count(*) as img_count,
    barcode,
    item_code
from images
inner join imports
    on import_id = imports.id
group by
    filename,
    barcode,
    item_code
order by
    item_code desc,
    barcode;
```

Note that ideally you should use table aliases in your query, which would have allowed us to figure out to which tables each column belongs.

Answer (score 0):

You can try in below way - using aggregation and group by

```
select filename,count(*) as img_cnt,barcode,item_code 
from images join imports on import_id = imports.id
group by filename,barcode,item_code
order by item_code desc, barcode
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this

```
SELECT 
filename  , COUNT(*) as Img_Count, item_code, barcode
FROM images inner join imports on import_id = imports.id
order by item_code desc, barcode;
GROUP BY barcode,item_code,filename
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query is missing a `group by`.  But, I would strongly encourage you to learn to write the query using qualified column names.  As written, someone reading the query has no idea where the columns are coming from.

I speculate that the columns are coming from `imports` -- but I should not have to guess:

```
select imp.filename, count(*) as img_count, imp.barcode, imp.item_code
from imports imp
     images i
     on i.import_id = imp.id
group by imp.filename, imp.barcode, imp.item_code;
```